# Menu Links not working in Mobiles/Tablets

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a AngularJS application which has a left to right menu slider of bootstap.
The problem is on clicking the links in the menu,page is not navigated.
This problem only occurs in every Mobile and Tab device not Laptops/Desktop.
On clicking the menu item,page should navigate and the menu should go inside right to left slider,but only the menu goes in.
I know the click event is workig as the menu goes in on a click event.
What could be the issue.
I tried the z-index, to check if other part of the pages are overalaping with menu but it doesnt make any diference.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap Javascript components will never work with Angular JS views 
because the views in Angular loads via HTTP request which mean when bootstrap javascript fires there is no DOM element to attach event listener

The solution is to use Angular Bootstrap

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

all component is Angular directives so it fire after views loading

Comment: It was working fine until now,we did not change any library,nothing.Now I dont know how it stopped working

Comment: It works now,there was a problem with angular touch,resolved it.

Comment: Congrats!. one question please. Do you using ngRoute module?